# azure stream analytics alert based on input telemetry data

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

How can we send an alert message to table storage if one of the telemetry inputs is greater than the threshold set in Reference JSON?
How would one convert threshold will comparison to "Alert output"?

Comment: Can you provide any more details?  Need some more information on your environment and setup.  For instance what uses Reference.json? From your description perhaps this is something a Logic App can help achieve or possibly send a message to an Event Hub

Answer (score 1):

for this you need to define the telemetry input as stream, and the threshold input as reference data. You can use either blob storage or SQL for reference data
Then do a reference data JOIN as specified here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/reference-data-join-azure-stream-analytics
Let me know if you have any further question.

Thanks,
Jean-Sebastien (Azure Stream Analytics).

Comment: how would you recommend implementing the actual alerts based on the output? Especially in a way that does not send out an alert every single time the input telemetry was above the threshold (let's say the sensor malfunctions for a few minutes, you don't want an email every single second).

Comment: Hi, you can use IsFirst function to only trigger an alert if this is the first time you see the condition in X seconds. Here's an example: SELECT device, value, System.timestamp() FROM input
WHERE ISFIRST(second, 30) OVER (WHEN value > 50)=1

Comment: @Jean-Sébastian thanks, would you then let Azure Functions do the actual alerting, or is there a better way to do it? Would it work to load this data into Log Analytics and then use the log analytics workspace interface to set up alerts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your reference JSON is stored in SQL you can use GetArrayElements to convert the reference data.Probably [this](http://learniotwithzain.com/2019/08/alert-engine-using-azure-stream-analytics-and-sql-azure-as-reference-data/) is closest to the one which you are trying  but here I have used SQL Database as reference rather than blob storage.